# Ошибка stray \221

Tags: c++

Что это за ошибка, когда появляется и как с ней бороться?

> [Error] stray '\221' in program

Comment: Следует проверить не закралась ли где-то русская буква, например `с` (эс) вместо английской `c` (си). Чтобы сказать более конкретно нужно видеть код программы.

Comment: @alexolut действительно, большое спасибо))

Answer (score 1):

Это означает что в коде (не в строковом литерале) есть байт с кодом 0221. Это например может быть символ `‘` в кодировке cp-1251, или какой-то другой символ в другой кодировке. Компилятор не знает что с этим делать и выдает соответствующую ошибку.

Answer (score 0):

Скорей всего имеет место некорректный символ в символьной строке. Например, вместо двух слэшов `\\` используется один `\`. Или используется какой-нибудь типографский символ, например, символ кавычек (левые и правые кавычки), которых нет в основном наборе символов языка.

Comment: У меня возникает в функции, которой передается параметром `const char string []`, в инструкции `char ch[]=string` при любых значениях

Comment: @FMIG Это неверное предложение. Вы не можете так инициализировать символьные массивы.

Comment: А как правильно тогда? Просто по другому char* не приводит к const char*

Comment: @FMIG На мой взгляд это вообще бессмысленный код. Вы что-то делаете неправильно. Но, если говорить конкретно, то вы должны скопировать символы из строки в символьный массив.